# installing SC Hotfix 513229-1.zip using Azure Pipeline

Tags: pipelines

I want to install SC Hotfix 513229-1.zip for Sitecore XP 9.1.1. https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000489. I want to push this to Release Pipeline. I had done numerous times installed using VMs but not through Azure Pipeline/Repos. How to do this?

Comment: Does this thread answer your question https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19177/how-to-manage-sitecore-hotfixes

Comment: Can help you: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35361/cumulative-hotfix-for-sitecore-xp-10-3/35362#35362

Answer (score 0):

If your regular build artifacts do not have Sitecore vanilla assemblies and files, then you can install the package *once* using 'Install a package' link in Sitecore Control Panel. This is sufficient.

Otherwise - this may not be an elegant way but it does what is needed.

1. You can extract the package.zip which is inside .update package file using 7-Zip.
2. Copy the content of *addedfiles, addedfolders and changedfiles* into a single folder and keep it your repo.
3. Install the update package in standalone environment, serialize the
   *addeditems and changeditems* content to your regular content serialization process.
4. Add a task in Azure Pipeline to copy the content from #2 step after the artifacts are copied. Content will be synched as part of your content serialization process.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the detailed steps provided.