# Cumulative hotfix for Sitecore XP 10.3

Tags: security, installation, patch-configuration

I am trying to install '**Cumulative hotfix for Sitecore XP 10.3**' source at [here](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002844).

I am using `Sitecore 10.3.0 (XP0/XP1)` currently. which is correct solution for the `10.3.0` site as one of the following solutions,

1. Cumulative Hotfix On Top Of Any Updates - A hotfix is installed on top of the initial release or any other update release. source at [here](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002844#CumulativeHotfixOnTopOfAnyUpdatesOn-premAndPaaS%5D)
2. Cumulative Hotfix On Top Of The Latest Update - A hotfix is installed on top of the latest update release. source at [here](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002844#CumulativeHotfixOnTopOfTheLatestUpdateOn-premAndPaaS)

Comment: Kindly add some more details of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the hotfix packages are the same so you can use any of them.

Just take care of the on-prem (your local developer environment) and PaaS.

1. For on-prem, from the `Sitecore 10.3.x rev. xxxxxx PRE/Platform Patch/OnPremCumulative` folder.
2. For PaaS, from the `Sitecore 10.3.x rev. xxxxxx PRE/Platform Patch/CloudCumulative` folder.

To install you can follow the below steps:

1. Create one separate project in your solution named `SitecoreHotfix.Patch` or any other name convenient for you.
2. Add all the cumulative hotfix package files in the same project with the correct file or folder path.

[image]

See blog post for more details: [Sitecore Cumulative Hotfixes Installation on OnPrem and PaaS](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2023/05/sitecore-cumulative-hotfixes-installation-onprem-and-paas.html)